# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard, nib

I've got a masterdetail application that throws the error;

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 
'NSBundle </Users/Alex/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/A301CCC3-21B3-4AB7-9209-72230036B148/EasyWake.app> (loaded)'
with name 'Ah7-4n-0Wa-view-MMQ-IT-qOo' and directory 'Main.storyboardc''
```

The masterview consists of a tableview completely constructed programmatically, some cells have buttons, uitextfields, or are standard subtitle cells with disclosure button.

The App loads as expected, & runs as expected for a couple minutes, but afterwards if I select a row, the app will crash.

I cannot figure out why this error is being thrown; searched SO and tried other solutions, checked bundle resources, I've got no known leaks or unused arrays that I know about. If anyone could shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, Alex

Error Stacktrace;

```
*** First throw call stack:(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x018861e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x016058e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01885fbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
3   UIKit                               0x0057ab7b -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 951
4   UIKit                               0x003e36f5 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
5   UIKit                               0x003e3e9d -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
6   UIKit                               0x003e40d3 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
7   UIKit                               0x003e45d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
8   UIKit                               0x003fe942 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 778
9   UIKit                               0x0040b8f7 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
10  UIKit                               0x0040c4e9 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
11  UIKit                               0x0054d0d1 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
12  UIKit                               0x0af2521b -[UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility(SafeCategory) layoutSubviews] + 50
13  UIKit                               0x00334964 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0161782b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
15  QuartzCore                          0x0201145a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
16  QuartzCore                          0x02005244 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
17  QuartzCore                          0x020050b0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
18  QuartzCore                          0x01f6b7fa _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
19  QuartzCore                          0x01f6cb85 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
20  QuartzCore                          0x01f6d258 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0184e36e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
22  CoreFoundation                      0x0184e2bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
23  CoreFoundation                      0x0182c254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
24  CoreFoundation                      0x0182b9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
25  CoreFoundation                      0x0182b7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
26  GraphicsServices                    0x021b95ee GSEventRunModal + 192
27  GraphicsServices                    0x021b942b GSEventRun + 104
28  UIKit                               0x002c5f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
29  EasyWake                            0x00010bfd main + 141
30  libdyld.dylib                       0x026b9701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

As requested, the code for select ROW;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
self.currentCell = indexPath;
switch ([indexPath section]) {
    case MACHINES:{
        if (self.WOLMachines.count <=0)return;
        self.wakeRequested = true;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
        break;
    }

    case DISCOVEREDMACHINES:{
        if (self.DiscoveredMachines.count <=0)return;
        self.wakeRequested = true;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
        break;
    }

    case ABOUT:
        NSLog(@"About Pressed");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showInfo" sender:self];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
self.currentCell = indexPath;
switch ([indexPath section]) {
    case MACHINES:{
        if (self.WOLMachines.count <=0)return;
        self.wakeRequested = false;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
        break;
    }

    case DISCOVEREDMACHINES:{
        if (self.DiscoveredMachines.count <=0)return;
        self.wakeRequested = false;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
        break;
    }

    case ABOUT:
        NSLog(@"About Pressed");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showInfo" sender:self];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Comment: What's your code once you select a row?

Comment: Added in question, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> > The App loads as expected, & runs as expected for a couple minutes, but afterwards if I select a row, the app will crash.
> >
> > reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:

1. Let's double check the name when you performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail". This name is the same with the name in story board
2. Turn one all Exception to catch this error.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi there, @"showDetail" & @"showInfo" match to their respective labels in storyboard. I can select rows/disclosure buttons fine (detail view loads) for the first couple minutes.

Comment: It's strange! I performSegueWithIdentifier with my own project, it works. Could you please send your project? I will debug for you.

Comment: Sure, It's zipped here; https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15475130/EasyWakeApp.zip

Comment: So sad, I downloaded, compile error. no such file or directory ping.m. net/if_types : file not found. Can not help you now

Comment: Were you trying on the simulator or an actual device? the includes only work for the simulator (I have different includes for a device)